# Table not being rendered correctly in final post

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, tables

I included a markdown table in my post ([How to use scoped APIs with (GSI) Google Identity Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815693/how-to-use-scoped-apis-with-gsi-google-identity-services))

### This is what my table looks like in the editor:

> [image]

### This is the edit preview:

> [image]

### But in the final post it appears broken and not like how it was in the preview

> [image]

I'm running safari on macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 and Apple Silicon (M1)

I don't think this is an Apple silicon issue however.

Comment: You only need one `-`, so `| - | - | - |` should do fine for that second line.

Comment: Add a linebreak before the first/ header row. You'll avoid most issues like this if you add blank lines between syntax elements (eg. tables, headers, block quotes, etc.).

Comment: I had the same issue, adding newline before and after worked. HOWEVER, i believe that preview and post should behave in the same way. Thus in my opinion a bug